# Supplier Survey Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

With my picture I'm trying to figure out what formula to use when adding the number of points that a different from one another (8) and (28) to add up to (36 total points).

Yet have a different formula when entering the score.

Comment: So do you want to extract the numbers from the text? Please explain how you want to use them to achieve your result.

Comment: So the reviewer will enter 0,1 or 2 in the white box underneath the blue column. This then adds 9 points per 1 point given under the total box. My current formula under total points says =E15+E16*9. But since both A and B are worth different points, how do I add them up to still equal the total points but in different point totals.

Comment: Do you mean `E15*14+E16*4`?

Comment: I've never used Excel before, but that did it! thank you so much!

Comment: How do I let people know you answered this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer as also commented:
`=E15*14+E16*4`

Instead of considering each score equally, give them different weight based on the total achievable score.